# Regulating D.C. motor - Feedback

Tags: motor, dc-motor

I purchase the following hobbyist motor:

http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/PKN12EB105C1/P14353-ND/2417077

How can I get a feedback from this motor? The design of D.C. motor that I found on Internet are open loop "regulation" if you can call it regulation, but if I want to implement a PID I need a measurement of the current speed or position depending of the kind of regulation.

How can you measure the speed/position of these hobbyist motors?

Comment: What kind of accuracy are you looking for and what do you mean by "kind of regulation?"

Comment: @EM Fields It is purely for hobbyist/education about motor so I don't need something very precise. I used kind of regulation, because open loop isn't regulation, if a charge is applied to an open loop motor, the motor will not reach the command speed if you don't have a feedback to correct the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a feedback of something, you need a sensor for that something. To get a position or speed of a motor, people usually use some kind of position encoder (optical, magnetic or maybe some other technology I am not aware of). Your motor is obviously lacking such a sensor. So your option would be spending more on your hardware and buy a motor with an integrated encoder. Or install a position sensor elsewhere on your system, such that you can measure the motor speed/position *indirectly*.

Comment: or senseless speed control

Comment: @JonRB With *THIS* motor? Actually I haven't heard of a sensorless control for brushed DC motors.. And it is good only for high speeds, which is driving it useless for position control.

Comment: @EugeneSh. So installing/building some sort of cheap tachometer is out ?

Comment: @MathieuL I think the resulting accuracy just won't justify the effort.

Comment: "Senseless."  Lol.  Anyway, sensorless brushless controls rely on the fact that there are multiple phases that are turning off and on during commutation such that you can read the back-emf of the off-phase and then estimate rotor position (and speed) of the rotor.  Brushed-type motors don't allow us to do that.

Comment: @EugeneSh. not fully true on both accounts. You can use senseless control with brushed motors (only speed, but that's all that is normally needed) and it can operate at low speed. The low spd/high speed concern plaguing senseless is to-do with BLAC/DC where position sensing is essential and they have concerns at zero speed & breakout.

Comment: @Eric its a BRUSHED motor, not brushless. the backEMF can be measured between switching events to determine the approx speed w.r.t. Ke. Equally brushedDC can operate "openloop" perfectly fine, unlike BLAC/DC where rotor position information is key to commutation

Comment: Likewise during rotation, the commutation results in a degree of ripple on the current (in additional to PWM & the stator inductance). This can be used to determine speed --> feedback into a PID

Comment: @JonRB It is probably possible in general. Do you think it is practical?

Comment: practical yes. in this case... dunno... your DClink needs to be greater than your expected mean voltage (to ensure you have < 100% modulation). and then comes downto MISPS' you could do the BackEMF sense method in an Arduino esp if the pwm freq is relatively low

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways to do this:

1. Add a sensor
2. Measure the back EMF

Eugene nailed #1, so I'll just expand on #2 a little bit.  Back EMF is simply the motor being a generator instead.  If you spin it mechanically, you'll get a voltage out of it, and that voltage works against the incoming "juice".

You can't measure it while powering the motor, so you'll have to slip in a reading between PWM pulses.  Depending on which microcontroller you're using, it might be able to do that in hardware; else you'll have to bit-bang the PWM just so you can start the ADC manually at the right time.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the speed regulation by using IR compensation. Measure the armature current, calculate the IR drop in the winding and adjust the voltage accordingly.